# Can sklearn SVM be performed using numpy 16bit float in python? If not, is there an alternate package

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform image segmentation using machine learning (SVM in particular). I am segmenting MRIs and the original images are 512x512x100. I have created 78 features per image. At that image size and number of features I quickly run out of memory.

To resolve the memory issue I have done a couple of things. 1) I down sampled the images to 256x256x50. I also reduced the precision to 16bit float as the original image is 16bit and so I didn't believe it necessary to have more precise data than that. (Maybe I'm wrong here.)

So. I was able to reduce the memory of my data to an amount that can be held in memory 6GB. Until I went to actually use the SVM function in sklearn and my computer quickly started using swap memory as it had run out of ram (16gb). I went searching a bit and found on the sklearn docs (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) that "If X and y are not C-ordered and contiguous arrays of np.float64 and X is not a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, X and/or y may be copied." This along with other posts on github made me realize the data was being scaled up to flaot64 and therefore taking up all my memory, as going from 16 to 64 from what I gather would increase the ram from 6 to 24gb... which goes beyond what I have available.

Here is a simple example of the code. Features is a bumpy array of 39,321,600 (256*256*50*12[training images]) by 78 (the features) and segmentations is 39,321,600 by 1 with values between 0-6 for the various regions of interest.

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(features, segmentations)
```

Above is the only code that is relevant at this point as I haven't gotten past the training portion.

Any help with either training a dataset of this size using SVM and sklearn, or any other options would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Anthony.

PS. I have performed a subsampling of the data as an option. Though, this is not ideal as I would like to use the whole image. If this is my best bet I guess I will pursue.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how best to revise your post.

Comment: I've made edits. Hopefully this is better. Any guidance otherwise would be appreciated.

Comment: can you include the feature extraction code as well? from the way you've described it it sounds like you're creating 78 features for every single pixel ?!

Comment: actually maybe this is ok, but if i understand correctly you're trying to train your model on 40M rows of data, this is way too much, maybe try again with 1-4M

Comment: I know this is not exact answer to your question, but you can try other classifier at first, maybe it will give you enough accuracy. Look here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html
They recommend SGDClassifier for big datasets, using it you can use partial_fit method, and learn classifier by batches, reading them from HDD one by one.

Comment: @maxymoo you are correct, it is for each pixel and is actually 3B pixels. I would include the features code... but its a lot of code. Would your suggestions be to sample more pixels from the region of interest?

Comment: @Olologin thanks for that answer. I had tried SGD early on when I think I had other issues I might try to give it another go.

Comment: @maxymoo sorry  that wasn't completely correct. You are right on the number of pixels per image. If I to sub-sample, should it be from the primary region of interest? or just random? In papers that have done similar they have typically used 25+ training images. Is there any point in increasing the number of training images if Im only sub-sampling from them? The entire image has a segmentation value (0-6) but the primary region is cartilage (its knee MRIs) and the cartilage is quite small within the image. So I don't want to under represent the region of interest.

Comment: that's a good point, why don't you try just undersampling the region of non-interest, and include all the points from your region of interest. the probabilities from the model will no longer be true, however as a classifier, you should still be fine